# How to add submodules in a Python Library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, pypi, python-packaging

I have created a python library whose structure looks like this.

```
|/library_name
|    |__init__.py
|    |/subpackage
|    |   |__init__.py
|    |   |
|setup.py
|setup.cfg
|LICENSE
```

Now when i published in pypi, I couldn't see the inner subpackages installed along with it. What should I do? What should be in outer `__init__.py`. Assume inner `__init__.py` has classes which I have written. Somebody please help how to add subpackages to the python library.

Here's the setup.py format

```
setup(
  name = 'package',         
  packages = ['package'],
  version = '1.0.1',
  license='GNU General Public Version 3',
  description = 'Package is the open source Python Library for solving various AI needs',
  long_description = long_description,
  long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
  author = ['Vigneshwar K R'],
  author_email = 'mymail@gmail.com',
  url = 'https://github.com/ToastCoder/repo',
  download_url = 'https://github.com/ToastCoder/repo/archive/master.zip',
  keywords = ['ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE', 'TENSORFLOW'],
  install_requires=['tensorflow'],
  classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
    'Intended Audience :: Education',
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',      
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9'
  ],
)
```

Comment: What does your `setup.py` look like? Maybe you forgot to add `find_packages`?

Comment: Could you please mention what it does?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I have added contents in setup.py. Kindly check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you share said `setup.py` & `__init__.py` codes please ?

I see two ways to deal with this :

- make the content from `lib/submodule` available from the top level : in `lib/__init__.py` add `from submodule import *`, then add every imported name in `__all__`. As far as i know, this is bad practice everywhere BUT inside of `__init__.py`s
- add the submodule directory to setup.py's `packages` parameter : `packages=["lib", "lib.submodule"]`

edit: as i expected, `submodule` is missing from the [`packages` parameter,](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) so it is not considered needed.

the `find_packages` option commented about has the same effect as adding `lib.submodule` to the packages list, it is mainly used in large libraries where adding every single module manually would be a pain.

Comment: I have updated setup.py format in the same question. kindly check it out. Also which __init__.py you are asking? the outer or the inner __init__.py

Comment: `lib.__init__.py` is meant to be the outter one, the one at the top level.
Also, i edited my answer